# WinAPI: codesign a directory

Tags: security, winapi, authenticode

Is it possible to code-sign and validate a directory on Windows? Basically, something like MacOS bundle directory codesigning and validation?

Comment: Code signing (Authenticode) is only for files (binaries, .msi, etc.)

Comment: Authenticode signature are always just for the file that is signed. May be the new app bundle formats developed for the Microsoft store (MSIX) allows to sign a bundle, but I don't know if this is just a transport signature or if it can be verified as app run-time. BTW: IMHO the Apple bundle signature is illogical at least the way you have to create it as there is no way to sign everything in a directory, instead you have to manually sign all executables and in the end the main binary.